# Beginner Java attempt: am I using too much memory?

Tags: java

I am new to Java. I am taking a lynda dot com course online to start off. The course asks you to write a simple program:

1. Ask the user to input 2 values
2. Ask the user to input an operation
3. use the operation on the 2 values and print the result

Here is what I wrote, it was very different from the solution given by the course. Could anyone take a quick look at it and tell me if there's something I'm doing fundamentally wrong or inefficient? My suspicion is that I'm using too much memory. Thank you so much for any help! For the record, my code worked:

```
package com.example.java;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter a numeric value: ");
        String input1 = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter a numeric value: ");
        String input2 = scanner.nextLine();

        double double1 = Double.parseDouble(input1);
        double double2 = Double.parseDouble(input2);

        System.out.print("Choose and operation (+ - * /): ");
        String input3 = scanner.nextLine();

        double resultAdd = double1 + double2;
        double resultSub = double1 - double2;
        double resultMul = double1 * double2;
        double resultDiv = double1 / double2;

        switch (input3) {
            case "+":
                System.out.println("The answer is " + resultAdd);
                break;
            case "-":
                System.out.println("The answer is " + resultSub);
                break;
            case "*":
                System.out.println("The answer is " + resultMul);
                break;
            case "/":
                System.out.println("The answer is " + resultDiv);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is what the instructor wrote, for the record:

```
package com.example.java;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Calculator2 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s1 = getInput("Enter a numeric value: ");
    String s2 = getInput("Enter a numeric value: ");
    String op = getInput("Choose an operation (+ - * /):");

    double result = 0;

    try {
        switch (op) {
            case "+":
                result = addValues(s1, s2);
                break;
            case "-":
                result = subtractValues(s1, s2);
                break;
            case "*":
                result = multiplyValues(s1, s2);
                break;
            case "/":
                result = divideValues(s1, s2);
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Unrecognized operation!");
                return;
        }

        System.out.println("The answer is " + result);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Number formatting exception " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

private static double addValues(String s1, String s2) {
    double d1 = Double.parseDouble(s1);
    double d2 = Double.parseDouble(s2);
    return d1 + d2;
}

private static double subtractValues(String s1, String s2) {
    double d1 = Double.parseDouble(s1);
    double d2 = Double.parseDouble(s2);
    return d1 - d2;
}

private static double multiplyValues(String s1, String s2) {
    double d1 = Double.parseDouble(s1);
    double d2 = Double.parseDouble(s2);
    return d1 * d2;
}

private static double divideValues(String s1, String s2) {
    double d1 = Double.parseDouble(s1);
    double d2 = Double.parseDouble(s2);
    return d1 / d2;
}

private static String getInput(String prompt) {
    System.out.print(prompt);
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    return sc.nextLine();
}
```

}

Comment: Try http://codereview.stackexchange.com instead.

Comment: What makes you think you're doing something wrong, or using too much memory?  This is probably better suited for codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: I don't think so - you use three more variables than the other solution which is perfectly fine. Who cares about some constant memory :)

Comment: Maybe post the instructor's code on codreview too. I can see a number of potential improvements in it.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'll post this on codereview.

Comment: Instructor code has some points: like duplicating code for parsing inputs.

Comment: I was also thinking about the unnecessary `catch Exception`, rather than catching the specific exception.

Comment: @AndyTurner `Double.parseDouble(...)` can `throw` `NumberFormatException`

Comment: @DimaMaligin exactly: that is a lot more specific than `Exception`. You should only catch `Exception` if something you call throws - *specifically* - `Exception`.

Comment: @AndyTurner I didn't `catch` the last part of your comment.. ;) you are right, still the argument passed to the `catch` block **will** be `NumberFormatException` even if it initialized as `Exception`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very simple java program which doesn't involve storing objects in the heap memory so you will be fine. Just incase you are wondering what are java objects, see

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objects.html

If you concern is on declaring/using too many local variables then you are alright because local variables are stored in the stack and the memory they use will be freed once the function ends. For you instance your the memory held by these variables will be available to your computer again once your main method finish running, that is when your program ends.

Java's garbage collection mechanism is pretty good at cleaning up for you. So don't ever be too worried about such instance until you see the out of memory exception.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/OutOfMemoryError.html

BTW efficiency wise, your tutor's code is better than yours because he is only doing the mathematical operation once whereas for your case you are doing them all and only printing the desire result, so you are basically making 3 redundant operations.

Your code is also less robust than your tutor's. What if the user enters XXX as 1 of the numeric input? I think your program will crash while trying to convert XXX into double data type.

Also, if the user enters abc as the operation input then nothing is printed.

But also note that your tutor's code can be improved as well, e.g. he is catching a general exception and making assumption that it will be a number formatting issue.